# using windows authentication with active directory groups as roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I've read several questions on this topic, 
such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833059/authenticate-user-using-active-directory-windows-authentication-in-ms-access-200), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398079/getting-user-roles-groups-from-active-directory-mvc3), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610/windows-active-directory-user-groups) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209242/asp-net-role-based-authentication-using-security-groups-in-active-directory);
but none have provided a working solution in my case.

**What I want to do:**

Implement Windows authentication for a web app that is only used by our own employees.  This way they should not need to log into the app, but already be authenticated by way of having logged into windows.

Also, I need to restrict certain areas of the app, based on Active Directory Security Groups that the user may be assigned to.

So I want to be able to decorate Controllers / Actions with

```
[Authorize(Roles="SomeRole")]
```

**What I've tried:**

I have

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

in my web.config.  And I have added several permutations of a `<roleManager>` as found in some of the posts linked to above.  Currently I have this role manager

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="WindowsProvider"
  enabled="true"
  cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <add
          name="WindowsProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

as found in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowstokenroleprovider.aspx) post.

As it is, if I decorate a controller with `[Authorize]`, I can access it fine.

**However:**

I can see in my user settings on the network, that I am part of a AD security group called "IT".  But if I decorate the same controller with `[Authorize(Roles="IT")]` I get the blank screen that is is served by the asp.net development server for a 401 not authorized.  **This is unexpected.**  I would think that I should be able to view the page as I am logged in to windows and am part of the group "IT".

Most everything I am finding on this topic make it sound very simple to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I am clearly missing something here.

Comment: Have you set up the ASP.NET membership provider to use Active Directory, too? Not just the role provider....

Comment: @marc_s I do have ASpNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider set as the default in web.config.  I can post that if you feel there could be an error there causing the problem.

Comment: This is an old thread, but with AD security, do you need to specify the domain? [Authorize(Roles = @"domainname\SomeRole")]

Answer (score 43):

For dev I am using IISExpress 
with development server properties of the MVC project set up so that
Anonymous Authentication is Disabled and Windows Authentication is Enabled.
The web config is deployed using our TFS build server to test and release servers for which authentication is also setup as above and works in those locations as well.

In my web.config I have.

```
  <system.web> 
....
       <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
....

    </system.web>
```

I can use

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\ADGroup")]
Public ActionResult Index()
{...}
```

or

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
            if (User.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\ADGroup"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("IRSAdmin");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

After i remember to logoff and log back in so the permission i was given to the AD group were applied.

Comment: Additional note in case, like me, you're banging your head against the desk for several hours trying to fix this: Logoff/Logon only picks up your new credentials when you're physically connected to the company network... when your wireless connection doesn't come up until AFTER logging in then your machine won't pick up the new group memberships from the Domain Controller and you will be left scratching your head for a while...

Comment: @DanielHume that's because AD syncs best on wired connections. You can just run gpupdate on the command line for the same effect