# How can I use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider with ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm learning to use .NET Identity. I have to authenticate to Active Directory. For that purpose I am trying to use `ActiveDirecotoryMembershipProvider`. I have to:

1. Authenticate user/password against [Active Directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) (AD).
2. Check whether user is present in my own database.

I configured it in my `web.config` to use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` as the default membership provider. Then I overrode `PasswordSignInAsync` method in my `ApplicationSignInManager` class (which inherits `SignInManager`) as follows -

```cs
public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    var adok = Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(userName, password);
    if (adok)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
        if (user == null)
            return Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.Failure);
        else
        {
            base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
            return Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.Success);
        }
    }
    else
        return Task.FromResult<SignInStatus>(SignInStatus.Failure);
}
```

This seems to work. But I think it's not the right way to do it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Here is how I called the above mentioned:

```cs
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, isPersistent: false, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View();
}
```

According to the answers I got, I should not call the Membership `Validate` method inside `PasswordSignInAsync`. I agree with that. In fact, I think overriding the method is wrong as well.

It was also suggested that I use `UserLogins` where I would give my AD an provider ID. But the only way I can think of using this is as follows -

```cs
IList<UserLoginInfo> loginInfos = await SignInManager.UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(username);
var valid = false;
foreach(var info in loginInfos)
{
    valid = Membership.Providers[info.ProviderKey].ValidateUser(username, password);
    if (valid)
        break;
}
```

So, if I want to authenticate a user against multiple Providers, I can create a provider key for each of them and assign those provider keys to the users. And this code will validate the user against them. But where should I put this code? What convention should I follow?

I am not keen on coding the AD validation myself, because I think `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` can do a better job than my own code. Also for both cases I have to add reference to `System.DirectoryServices` anyway.

Comment: don't just down vote, leave a comment so that i can understand your reasoning behind the down vote.

Comment: I think maybe you were down voted as there does not seem to be a clear problem to your post.  You have code that works, but want suggestions on other avenues.  This would be better suited to the Code Review portion of the site:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why? I have clearly stated what I want in my question. I may have code that works but that doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: have a look at this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767439/using-windows-authentication-with-active-directory-groups-as-roles/17226421#17226421

Comment: @ozhug, I have seen this. It uses windows authentication. But I need forms authentication in two levels as I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to mix MembershipProviders with identity.  What you most likely want to do, is treat logging into ActiveDirectory similar to how identity treats other external logins (like google/facebook).

This basically boils down to storing the AD username as a login:

`userManager.AddLogin(<userId>, new UserLoginInfo("ActiveDirectory", "<ADUserName>")`

If you only login via AD, then you could indeed override PasswordSignIn to explicitly [validate against AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)

Otherwise, you'd want this in only the specific login flow for AD, preserving the existing local password/social login functionality.

Comment: I am not sure how to configure Active Directory as External Login. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: When a user is created or an existing user wants to link an AD login, you need expose this in your app UI flow.  That is when you would call the AddLogin code above.

Comment: There's no magic to configure, you just need to pick a providerID constant for AD in your app.  The external login table already is setup by identity, you just need to use the feature.

Comment: I am not using the built in database or EF. The database in use is custom. So basically I am implementing it from ground up. Where do I put the above mentioned code?

Comment: That's code that typically goes in the controller/page (application code) as opposed to identity code

Comment: where should I call `Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(userName, password)` ?

Comment: You don't, you should just directly validate against AD yourself in code instead of using ADMembershipProvider, the link in my answer shows some relevant apis which might be useful

Comment: Even if I code it myself where would I put that code? In the controller? or somewhere else?

Comment: Controller or a new method in your ApplicationUserManager probably makes the most sense

Answer (score 0):

Try it once following step, may be it will helpful you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx

Comment: The link you provided does not use [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)