# Is there any roles authentication functionality built in to Windows Authentication in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'd like to use Windows Authentication with a new ASP.NET MVC project, but I will probably need roles based authentication functionality so that users of the app can be designated different roles by the application (e.g. Administrator, Approver, General User).

Is there any roles-based authentication functionality built in to Windows Authentication in ASP.NET or do you just have to just manually build this in yourself?

---

edit: the roles would be at application level- I can't make a business case to create 5 separate Active Directory groups, for example, for this application just to manage roles.  Is there some way to manage roles locally within the application?  I can build this out, but was wondering if Windows Authentication has this built in or not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use "RoleProvider" class to authenticate user roles by adding the roleManager configuration tag in web.config

Answer (score 0):

see this one about creating using windows authentication with windows groups

[using windows authentication with active directory groups as roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767439/using-windows-authentication-with-active-directory-groups-as-roles/17226421#17226421)