# MVC 5 AD and Local Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am coming from Coldfusion and starting to mess with MVC 5.

I had my Coldfusion sites set up so that when a user specified their username and password on a login form I would first check that against our AD server. If it found the person I would then know that they were valid as far as the organization goes, then I would check a local DB table to see if their username was there to verify that they had the rights to access this particular site in the organization. I do not want everyone in the AD server to be able to access the site, only those who have been designated to.

How would you go about something like this in ASP MVC? Is there a better/different way to accomplish this in ASP.NET? If anyone knows of any methods or resources to get me started I would appreciate it!

Comment: Look into role based security

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using windows authentication with active directory groups as roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767439/using-windows-authentication-with-active-directory-groups-as-roles)

Comment: He wants active directory group based auth, you can still makes roles independent of that though.

Comment: Thank you. Looking into role based security. That seems to be what I am looking to do.